# Powershell foreach alternative for item update

Tags: powershell

It takes forever to update items using foreach loop. Any other idea?

```
if((Get-PSSnapin | Where {$_.Name -eq "Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell"}) -eq $null) {
    Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell
}
$web=get-SPWeb "http://inside.nov.com/sites/sales/Apps"
$list=$web.Lists["Norton Security"]

$CAML = '<Where>
      <Or>
         <IsNull>
            <FieldRef Name="RanUpdate" />
         </IsNull>
         <Eq>
            <FieldRef Name="RanUpdate" />
            <Value Type="Boolean">False</Value>
         </Eq>
      </Or>
   </Where>'
$query = new-object Microsoft.SharePoint.SPQuery
$query.ViewAttributes = "Scope='Recursive'"

#$query.RowLimit = 10
$query.Query = $CAML
$listitems = $list.GetItems($query)
$count = $listitems.count

write-host $count
# End script
#Break
    if ($count -ge 1)
    {
        foreach($item in $listitems)
        {
            $item["Year"] = "2010"
            $item["RanUpdate"] = $true
            $item.SystemUpdate()
        }
    }

$web.dispose()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can perform a batch operation to do updates on many ListItems at once. [example](http://sharepointcore.blogspot.ca/2011/12/sharepoint-batch-updating-list-items.html).

Comment: Thanks. I am not sure if it will work in powershell. but will try.

Comment: Worst case scenery you can execute C# from powershell. [source](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/stefan_gossner/2010/05/07/using-csharp-c-code-in-powershell-scripts/)